# TfL says I must purchase a new Oyster card after failing to collect Auto top-up

Tags: online-resources, payment, tfl, oyster-card

I just checked my Oyster card online that I haven't used in a while and the 'Manage Auto top-up' page says:

> Your last Auto top-up request has not been collected. This may be due to a technical fault or because you did not collect it by making a journey with your Oyster card on, or before, 12/06/2015.
>
> Please check your Auto top-up request details below and resubmit your request if necessary.

However, there's no option to resubmit available. I contacted TfL about this and they said:

> Unfortunately as the card failed to collect the previous auto top up, this can no longer be added to the card. If you would like to set up auto top up again you will need to purchase a new Oyster card and this would need to be set up again.

I find it incredibly odd that they say it can be resubmitted online, but then don't offer the option (a bug?) and that I have to get a new card simply because I didn't collect it. Can't they just cancel the Auto top-up request on their system?

Has the customer service agent made a mistake?

Comment: FYI, you can just use a credit card instead: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52936/are-there-still-any-advantages-to-using-an-oyster-card-for-travel-in-london

Comment: What I have read on some unofficial forums is that TfL stops Oyster cards where auto-top-up has failed and the card holder didn't respond to the email TfL sends about it. The card is permanently cancelled. I have not made an answer of this as I haven't yet found an official source. But supposedly you should be able to get any balance transferred to a new card at a ticket office.

Comment: @JonathanReez Thanks for the info (I also use debit card for travel when appropriate), but it's not related to the question and doesn't apply to me in terms of the Oyster card itself.

Comment: Both credit and debit contactless bank cards can fully replace an oyster card.

Comment: @JonathanReez That's categorically wrong for the reasons stated in the link you cited, and as I stated, it's not related to the question and doesn't apply to me in terms of the Oyster card itself.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Do you have links to those "unofficial forums"? I checked my email and I received one on 24/06/15 saying _"I am writing to let you know that we have been unable to activate Auto top-up on your Oyster card. This may be because ... you didn't travel through your selected station in the specified time period. We have refunded your order back to the credit or debit card you assigned for Auto top-up. If you would still like to request Auto top-up, please submit a new order at oyster.tfl.gov.uk."_ There's no indication that I should respond or that the card would be cancelled.

Comment: I found a note [here](https://www.railforums.co.uk/threads/oyster-card-blocked-as-auto-top-up-didnt-work.157710/#post-3230343): "TfL have started a program whereby once a week they cancel cards where the auto-top-up has failed. So my card got cancelled." They didn't link to any documents or provide any source, so I can't say how reliable it is. I think there was another forum posting but I can't find it again right now.

Answer (score 3):

I have had this problem as well. If you select 'shopping basket' from the menu in your oyster account, you will find the option to add new purchases, where you can choose auto top up and make the new request.